# When i select the job properties it is always showing New job window

Tags: sql-server

I have the admin rights on the server and when i select job properties its always showing new job window and the user who is having same access able to view the job properties.
Please help me out in this

Answer (score 1):

This is an amazingly annoying bug with SQL Server Management Studio. You need to install [SQL Server SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=D07219B2-1E23-49C8-8F0C-63FA18F26D3A&displaylang=en) to fix the problem.